# Puppeteer - Removing elements by class

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I try to remove elements by classname but it doesn't work.

This is the code i used:

```
await page.screenshot({path: 'pic.png'});   //for testing purposes
    let div_selector_to_remove= ".xj7.Kwh5n";
    var thingToRemove = document.querySelectorAll(div_selector_to_remove);
    var number_of_elements = thingToRemove.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < number_of_elements.length; i++) {
        thingToRemove[i].parentNode.removeChild(thingToRemove);
    }
```

The browser loads and i get a screenshot with the elements loaded. The nothing happens. The elements remain there

Comment: How do you test that they are not removed? You're making a screenshot before. Are you sure that the elements were there when the code is evaluated? Did you try to debug thingToRemove ?

Comment: I used a non headless version of puppeteer. I could see the elements were still there in chromium.

Comment: [demo of something similar to what you're attempting](https://puppeteersandbox.com/6BaY3Erd)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Run `document.querySelector` inside `page.evaluate`. Here's my answer:

```
await page.goto('<url_here>');
let div_selector_to_remove= ".xj7.Kwh5n";
await page.evaluate((sel) => {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(sel);
    for(var i=0; i< elements.length; i++){
        elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(elements[i]);
    }
}, div_selector_to_remove)
```

Comment: Once again... You saved me... Thank you so much. I am new to puppeteer and i hadn't really  grasped page.evaluate().

Answer (score 5):

Probably easier...

Remove the first node matching `selector`:

```js
await page.$eval(selector, el => el.remove());
```

Remove all nodes matching `selector`:

```js
await page.$$eval(selector, els => els.forEach(el => el.remove()));
```

Wait for a selector, then remove it:

```js
const el = await page.waitForSelector(selector);
await el.evaluate(el => el.remove());
```

If for some reason you need to select and remove in console browser-land:

```js
const selector = ".foo";

// single
await page.evaluate(`
  document.querySelector("${selector}").remove()
`);

// multiple
await page.evaluate(selector =>
  document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(el => el.remove()),
  selector
);
```

You can hardcode the selector into the `eval` string/function as well but I figured it'd be useful to show it coming from a variable in two different ways just in case.

As with anything in Puppeteer, understanding which code runs in Node/Puppeteer-land and which code runs in browser/console-land is extremely important. The rule of thumb is: if it's a callback or stringified function body, it's in the browser and you can only use browser/DOM concepts like `HTMLElement.remove()`, `window` and `document`, otherwise it runs in Node and you can only call Puppeteer API functions. In OP's case, it looks like we're outside of a callback in Node-land, so `document` isn't a thing, only Puppeteer `page.` functions.

Answer (score 2):

First, `number_of_elements` is number.

But you call `number_of_elements.length`.

Next, `thingToRemove[i].parentNode.removeChild(thingToRemove)`, `thingToRemove[i].parentNode` is parent of `thingToRemove[i]`, not `thingToRemove`,

so you can't remove `thingToRemove` from `thingToRemove[i].parentNode`.

I think this code may be useful.

```
await page.screenshot({path: 'pic.png'});   //for testing purposes
let div_selector_to_remove= ".xj7.Kwh5n";
var thingToRemove = document.querySelectorAll(div_selector_to_remove);
var number_of_elements = thingToRemove.length;
for (var i = 0; i < number_of_elements; i++) {
    thingToRemove[i].parentNode.removeChild(thingToRemove[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    //Wait for the element with id="xe7COe" to show up
    await page.waitForSelector('#xe7COe');
    //delete the element with id="xe7COe"  
    await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#xe7COe').remove());
```

Comment: [`waitForSelector` returns the node it found](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#not-using-the-return-value-of-waitforselector-and-waitforxpath), so you can simplify your code to `const el = await page.waitForSelector('#xe7COe');` and then `await el.evaluate(el => el.remove())` rather than re-querying it. If you _do_ want to re-query it, or don't need to wait for it, prefer using `page.$eval` over `page.evaluate()`. `page.$eval` is a shorthand for the common pattern of running `document.querySelector` as the first thing in an `evaluate`.

Answer (score 1):

**Best Solution**
Run document.*querySelector* inside *page.evaluate*. Here's my answer

```
    await page.goto('<url_here>');
let div_selector_to_remove= ".xj7.Kwh5n";
await page.evaluate((sel) => {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(sel);
    for(var i=0; i< elements.length; i++){
        elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(elements[i]);
    }
}, div_selector_to_remove)
```